# Use modules on server without install permissions

Tags: node.js

Node.js is installed on a server that I have limited access to. I can upload files  to the server and execute scripts from the command line, but I cannot run certain commands like install.

I have a Node.js script uploaded to the server that I'd like to use. The script references other files, such as a file.json, that it accesses just fine. There's even some other modules it uses, like `const osPath = require( 'path' )` and `const crypto = require( "crypto" )`, that work just fine.

However, the script references something like `const argv = require('commander')`, but that gives me an error since the module is not installed.

If I download the [commander files](https://github.com/tj/commander.js), and uploaded them to the server, am I able to modify the require statement to point to where I uploaded the file? Or is all hope lost and I would need to find a server where I can run install commands?

Comment: Install the same version of Node.js on your own computer. Run `npm install commander` in the project folder on your own computer. Then upload the `node_modules` folder to your project folder on the server.

Comment: That's awesome, I wouldn't have thought of that. Is the only thing that's important the Node.js version? The server is Linux and my computer is Windows. Would that matter?

Comment: That shouldn't matter since a module is usually just a bunch of source code.